# Split Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have the CODE_X field of the TABLE_X table whose content is in the following format:

```
CODE02+CODE03+CODE01+......+CODE0n
```

my goal is to, into a PL/SQL procedure, split the content into several lines using the "+" separator to enhance the CODE_T field of the temporary table TABLE_T

```
CODE02
CODE03
CODE01
......
CODE0n
```

attention that the order of the data must not be changed.

After splitting the field I have to join with each of the values ​​intercepted with another table (TABLE_Y), for example

```
select NAME_Y from TABLE_Y A
inner join TABLE_T B
on A.CODE_Y=B.CODE_T
```

to obtaining a result similar to:

```
NAMECODE02
NAMECODE03
NAMECODE01
......
NAMECODE0n
```

where the order of the above names is the same as the previously split CODE.

After extracting the NAME I have to recompact them in the same way as CODE, to obtain a single field like:

```
NAMECODE02+NAMECODE03+NAMECODE01+......+NAMECODE0n
```

I hope I was clear and I thank you in advance for the help you will give me

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: hi Gordon, the version is 12.1.0.2.0 thank you

Answer (score 0):

To split the content as you show, no matter how many values you might have there

```
 SQL> select regexp_substr( 'code01+code02+code03+code4' , '[^+]+' , 1, level ) from 
      dual
      connect by regexp_substr( 'code01+code02+code03+code04' , '[^+]+' , 1, level )
      is not null
      /

REGEXP_SUBSTR('CODE01+CODE02+CODE03+CODE4','[^+]+',1,LEVEL)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
code01
code02
code03
code04
```

to going back from the rows to columns

```
SQL>  with t as ( select 'code1' as col from dual
  2   union all
 select 'code2' as col from dual
  3    4   union all
 select 'code3' as col from dual
  5    6   union all
  7   select 'code4' as col from dual
 ) select * from t pivot ( max(col) for col in ( 'code1' as code1, 'code2' as code2, 'code3' as code3, 'code4' as code4 ) )
 /
  8    9
CODE1 CODE2 CODE3 CODE4
----- ----- ----- -----
code1 code2 code3 code4

SQL>
SQL>
```

If you want a single record with the same separator

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1   with t as ( select 'code1' as col from dual
  2   union all
  3   select 'code2' as col from dual
  4   union all
  5   select 'code3' as col from dual
  6   union all
  7   select 'code4' as col from dual
  8   )
  9  select code1 || '+' || code2 || '+' || code3 || '+' || code4 as result
 10  from (
 11  select * from t pivot ( max(col) for col in ( 'code1' as code1, 'code2' as code2, 'code3' as code3, 'code4' as code4 ) )
 12* )
SQL> /

RESULT
-----------------------
code1+code2+code3+code4

SQL>
```

Of course, you have to include this in your PLSQL to dynamically calculate how many columns you might have ( of course limit is 1000, more than that is not possible )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function together with `level` pseudocolumn :

```
SELECT level AS id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( code_x, '[^\+]+', 1 , level ) AS code_x        
  FROM table_x t
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  REGEXP_COUNT( code_x, '\+') + 1
```

in order to unpivot the extracted values

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0205409aac97e75ae65ae1ab03772184)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
 with t1 as
      ( SELECT 'CODE5+CODE2+CODE8+CODE4+CODE1+CODE6' txt FROM dual
       )
    SELECT 'NAME'|| regexp_substr(txt, '[^+]+', 1, LEVEL) txt
 FROM t1
 CONNECT BY regexp_substr(txt, '[^+]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
   SQL> /

TXT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NAMECODE5
NAMECODE2
NAMECODE8
NAMECODE4
NAMECODE1
NAMECODE6
```

Combine above sql with listagg to recompact

```
   with t1 as
          ( SELECT 'CODE5+CODE2+CODE8+CODE4+CODE1+CODE6' txt FROM dual
           ),
        --replace NAME string with column NAME_Y from table_y
       t2 as (SELECT 'NAME'||regexp_substr(txt, '[^+]+', 1, LEVEL) txt
         FROM t1
         CONNECT BY regexp_substr(txt, '[^+]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
   
    
    select listagg(txt,'+') txt from t2
    SQL> /
    
    TXT
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NAMECODE5+NAMECODE2+NAMECODE8+NAMECODE4+NAMECODE1+NAMECODE6
```